# gmail api watch : Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to call [User: watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) from a python google cloud function.

I'm testing the script on my laptop.

Setup that I did:

1. enable gmail API on the project
2. create service account with json credential file
3. put the client ID of the service account into [Manage API client access](https://admin.google.com/) with the following API scopes `['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']`
4. verified that G Suite Domain-wide Delegation is enabled

The error I keep getting is:
`err=('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', '{\n  "error": "unauthorized_client",\n  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."\n}')`

I've tried passing the service credential accounts and setting userId = TARGET_INBOX and that just comes back with a bad request. I've tried looking at the other SO posts associated with this errors and I don't see anything that I've done wrong.

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pytest = "*"

[packages]
flask = "*"
google-cloud-pubsub = "*"
google-api-python-client = "*"
google-auth = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

watch_inboxes.py

```py
import os

import google.auth
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials
from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import json

from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

TARGET_INBOX = '***TARGET_EMAIL_ADDRESS****'


def watch_inboxes(request):
    
    if not os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']:
        exit(-1)

    creds, proj = google.auth.default()
    
    request = {
        'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
        'topicName': 'projects/***PROJECTNAME***/topics/***TOPICNAME****'
    }

    delegated_credentials = creds.with_subject(TARGET_INBOX)

    org_service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    org_rval = None

    try:
        org_rval = org_service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
    except HttpError as err:
        print("err={}, context={}".format(err, err.content))
    except RefreshError as err:
        print("err={}".format(err))

    print("org_rval={}".format(org_rval))

    return org_rval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your code it seems you forgot to add `scopes` to your [`google.auth.default()`-function](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html).

So the end product would look like this `google.auth.default(scopes)`